# Busy image keeps loading and response is not considered

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, compatibility

We have A Framed Application. In one of the process, when the page is submitted, we show a busy image until the response is received as the process might take 1+ minute.
    In IE11, the Application keeps on loading and never shows the result. But it works fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE Compatibility mode. Please see below for the code.

```
var myTop = form_input();
          if (typeof isaTop == 'function' && isaTop().header) {
             isaTop().header.busy(parent.form_input)
          }
          myTop.location.href = request;
function busy(frameObject) {

    try {
        with(frameObject.document){
            // get all the stylesheets from the header
            var allStylesheets = this.window.document.styleSheets;

            writeln("<html><head>");
            // add the css sheets
            for(var i = 0; i < allStylesheets.length; i++) {
                writeln('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="' + allStylesheets[i].href + '" />\n');
            }
            // add the rest
            writeln("</head>\n<body><div id='busy'>\n" +
                "<img src='<%=WebUtil.getMimeURL(pageContext, "b2b/mimes/images/busy.gif") %>' alt='<isa:UCtranslate key="b2b.busy.message"/>' />" +
                "<p><isa:UCtranslate key="b2b.busy.message"/></p>" +
                "</div></body></html>");
        }
        frameObject.document.close();
    }
    catch (e) {}
}

<frameset cols="*,15,0" id="fourthFS" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">
      <!--End of edit by Arshid to hide the history frame from startup of application-->
        <frameset rows="0,*" id="workFS" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">
          <frame name="documents" src="<isa:webappsURL name="/b2b/updateworkareanav.do" />" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" />
          <frame name="form_input" src="<isa:webappsURL name="/b2b/updatedocumentview.do?refresh=1" />"  frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" title="<isa:translate key="b2b.frame.jsp.forminput"/>" />
        </frameset>
        <frame name="closer_history" src="<isa:webappsURL name="/b2b/closer_history.jsp" />" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" title="<isa:translate key="b2b.frame.jsp.closerhistory"/>" />
        <frame name="_history" src="<isa:webappsURL name="/b2b/history/updatehistory.do" />" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" title="<isa:translate key="b2b.frame.jsp.history"/>" />
        <noframes>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </noframes>        
      </frameset>




We tried enabling IE Compatibilty mode by putting following code but we are not able to fix the issue. 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
Can some one please give us any clues or help?
Thanks,
Srinivas

    enter code here
```